# Using Fontawesome with SCSS, the :before content is changing

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome

So I'm using SCSS and fontawesome and it starts like this in the .scss file:

```
$fa-var-bitbucket-square: "\f172";
```

And when it compiles the CSS it ends up like this:

```
content: "";
```

Not only squares, all kinds of weird characters.
If I view it in the browser it looks more like this:

```
content: "ïƒ‰";
```

I'm not sure what is going on. The font is loading fine, the path is correct, etc. I've been scouring Google and haven't found an answer.

Thank you and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: What character set are you compiling into?

Comment: I am using charset "UTF-8" @2C-B

Comment: It seems that you don't need that setting. "Sass will always encode its output as UTF-8. It will include a @charset declaration if and only if the output file contains non-ASCII characters." (Source: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) That does not answer your question though.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry people, I just needed

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

In my html.

Embarrassed!